# MVC 4 Post data is resetting unchanged properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, properties, model-binding, reset

What I am trying to make is a view in which the properties of a model are displayed, and the option to change 1 property, in this case "Status" for which I made a helper.

I got to the point at which the changed property is correctly modified and changed, but somehow values of the other properties are now being resetted.

I am guessing this is because the post data is being used to modify the model and since some properties are unchangeable, I guess an empty value is used to update the model?

here is my controllers GET:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        ProductCode productcode = db.ProductCodes.Find(id);
        if (productcode == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(productcode);
    }
```

and here the POST:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ProductCode productcode)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(productcode).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(productcode);
    }
```

And finally the view:

```
@model PortalTMC.Models.ProductCode

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Change status";
}

<h2>Status veranderen</h2>
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
         <legend>ProductCode</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, "Id")
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code, "Product code")
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Code)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role, "Rol  (1 = Administrator  |  2 = Trainer  |  3 = User)")
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Role)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, "Status")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Status)
        </div>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Verander status" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Terug naar lijst", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

**Update:**

Unfortunately including or excluding the properties on the post method is not working :/ for example if I replace the post method to:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "Role, Code")] ProductCode productcode)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(productcode).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(productcode);
    }
```

I still end up with Role and Code being reset..

ProductCode is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PortalTMC.Models
{
    public class ProductCode
    {
        //PK
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }
        public ProductCodeStatus Status { get; set; }
        public int Role { get; set; }
    }

    public enum ProductCodeStatus
    {
        Active,
        Inactive,
        Pending,
    }
}
```

Comment: To see the definition of ProductCode would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

vtortola's suggestion is very valid that you should not be exposing your entities directly to the view. I will only explain why values of entity are being reset even after using `ExcludeAttribute`. Indeed they are not being reset. Model binder creates a new object which is populated with default values and then values from request are written to the object. Using `ExcludeAttribute` here will have no effect because what it does is that it simply ignores the values for excluded from request parameters. But still its a new object nevertheless (not the object from db). So if you want non editable values to be present in the model bound object you need to provide these values in the request object (hidden fields are one option).

Second option is that you omit the bound object from method and explicitly call model binding by the method `UpdateModel` like

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        var code = db.GetCode();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            UpdateModel(code, "Excluded properties as string seperated by comma");//plz check the correct overload of updatemodel
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    return View(code);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed to know and saved me quite some time!

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude properties from the binding with the [ExcludeAttribute](http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/tip-of-the-day-199-asp-net-mvc-defining-model-binding-explicitly/).

But definitely, do not expose data entities through MVC. Create input/output models that represents the information exchange between browser and server, so you have a fine grained control over that information, and if it is valid, then get the data entity and apply the values.

Cheers.